# Cannot enable XHTML submit input/button which is disabled by default

Tags: javascript, button, xhtml

I have this simple button in XHTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Test" disabled="disabled" onmouseover="this.disabled=''" />
```

The problem is, no matter what I try, when I hover over the button, it won't re-enable from the disabled attribute it has. In XHTML, you are required to use `disabled="disabled"` which seems to completely break the option to enable/disable it with JavaScript. I've tried running `this.disabled=''`, `this.disabled=false`, and even `this.removeAttribute('disabled')` but nothing seems to be capable of re-enabling the button. Weird thing is, if I remove the `='disabled'` part of the attribute (making it invalid XHTML), the script enables the button just fine. Is this not possible without using invalid XHTML?

**Note:** I'd really prefer to only use JavaScript for this specific example, not jQuery.

I thought this would be something simple that would take like 5 seconds but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled elements for some reason do not seem to fire mouseover/out events along with click.

The following is not the best solution in the world, but you can wrap it in another element and use the wrapping element's mouseover event to enable it.

```
<div style="display:inline-block;padding:1px;" onmouseover="document.getElementById('submit').disabled=false">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Test" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, very odd. I just added the mouse-over event to the form element rather than wrapping it in an element. Thanks. :)

Comment: The `div` doesn't receive a `mouseover` event if its entire area is occupied by the button, at least in Firefox. Your code only works because of the padding, which gives a 1px wide trigger area around the button.

Comment: @Søren, hence why I added it. :)

Comment: But it's entirely possible for the user to move the mouse onto the button without triggering a 1px `mouseover`, if the mouse is moved quickly enough. You can't generally count on getting a `mouseover` event for every single pixel the mouse is moved.

Answer (score 0):

`disabled=false` is correct.

The problem is that a disabled element doesn't receive events. See the question [Javascript OnMouseOver and Out disable/re-enable item problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823099/).